# How to import RESTful Server Hapi Fhir?

Tags: eclipse, rest, hapi-fhir

I want to build the simple RestServer Fhir. So for this, I have read this article http://jamesagnew.github.io/hapi-fhir/doc_rest_server.html.

At the end of the article, there is the link to download the simple server FHIR. This is the link

https://github.com/jamesagnew/hapi-fhir/tree/master/restful-server-example

Now I have this folder on my local pc and I have try to import this project on my workspace through eclipse but I'm not able to do this. I have this situation when I try to import this project

[image]

How can I import this project?

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but in Eclipse you probably want to try to use: Import -> Existing Maven Project   and point it to the pom.xml file in the folder you downloaded.